# Remove Non-ASCII characters from XML file C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to write a program to remove open an XML file with Non-ASCII characters and replace those characters with spaces and save and close the file.

Thats basically it, just open the file remove all the non ascii characters and save/close the file.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RemoveSpecial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pth_input = string.Empty;
            string pth_output = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                //input one
                string p_input = args[0];
                pth_input = p_input;
                pth_input = pth_input.Replace(@"\", @"\\");


                //output
                string p_output = args[2];
                pth_output = p_output;
                pth_output = pth_output.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
            }

            //s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);



            string lx;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pth_input))
            {
                using (StreamWriter x = new StreamWriter(pth_output))
                {
                    while ((lx = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();

                        Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
                        x.Write(text);
                    } sr.Close();

                }
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You have the answer in your code, commented out - use `Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);`

Comment: You of course realize that the meaning of the XML document could be changed. It could also be corrupted due to reading the file as UTF-8 when it might not have been encoding with UTF-8. It could also become not well-formed (invalid as XML). It could also become invalid per applicable schemas. Also, you aren't touching numeric character entity references (e.g., &#x1f6b2; instead of )  but it's unclear if that's your intention. In general, it best to use XML libraries to manipulate XML documents. You should consider these issues if you find that your success is only by happenstance.

Comment: It could be that saving the XML document with the document encoding as US-ASCII meets your requirements without changing the meaning of the XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx), the first string is an input parameter (and not passed by reference, so it could not change anyway). The result of the replacement is in the return value, like so:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
x.Write(result);
```

Note that `RegexOptions.Compiled` might decrease performance here. It makes sense only if you reuse the same regular expression instance on multiple strings. You can still do that, if you create the `RegEx` instance outside of the loop:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

using (var sr = new StreamReader(pth_input))
{
    using (var x = new StreamWriter(pth_output))
    {
        while ((lx = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            var result = regex.Replace(text, String.Empty);
            x.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```